# What would be the meaning of "You give me the awful impression […] of someone who hasn't read any of the arguments against your position ever"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, quotes

As a non native speaker I am facing trouble understanding one of the famous quotes from Cristopher Hitchens,

> "You give me the awful impression, I hate to have to say it, of someone who hasn't read any of the arguments against your position ever."

Can anyone explain what did he mean by the quote analysing phrase by phrase.

1. Why “the awful impression” instead of “an awful impression”?
2. What does it mean “hate to have to say it”?
3. Why “against your position” instead “against their/his/one’s position”?

Comment: “hate to have to say it” is a common idiom -- you should be able to find a discussion of it somewhere.

Comment: @HotLicks I know about “hate to say” but “hate to have to say” is new to me. Any reference would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I think that you should consider posting questions of this sort on SE English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "The" is used because  the speaker feels there is more or less a unique way to acknowledge what they sense. Otherwise, if you consider that the impression you have is just one among several possibilities described or that it is not well defined you use "an". This latter standpoint is made more definite when the author modifies "impression" by means of the adjectif "certain" (meaning "not well determined; difficult to describe"); then only "a" will be found ("*a certain impression*").

- The impression of being confined too narrowly had been a complaint of several persons.
- They were several to say that they had had an impression of narrow confinement.
- ([ref](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Morgan_s_Passing/NKU_xj9sK_cC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22had+an+impression+of+cold%22&pg=PA101&printsec=frontcover)) On his left was the kitchen; he had an impression of cold, gleaming whiteness. (*Here "the" wouldn't do because the impression of whiteness is not necessarily the same for everyone, nor is this impression too well defined.*)

[image]

2. It is a formula that is usually considered to aim at being polite to the person being addressed, but it is as well, more importantly and fundamentally, a way of telling that person that the idea of causing them  displeasure (in the sentence, by pointing out to them a shortcoming of theirs) is not enjoyable, that they don't do that out of sheer meanness, and that they are not indifferent to their problem. "Hate to have to say" is a little stronger: it expresses the fact that there is no way to avoid saying whatever is going to be said. "have" is a modal verb, used to express obligation.
3. It is "against *your*" because of a failure to realize agreement. It should be "their" or "his" or  "her" or "his/her", but not "one's", nor "your".